A virtually cyclic group $G$ cannot contain $F_2$

A virtually cyclic group $G$ cannot contain $F_2$.

This looks easy. Let $H = \langle a \rangle$ be a cyclic subgroup of $G$ with finite index. So let $G = g_1 H \sqcup g_2 H \sqcup \cdots \sqcup g_n H$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $g_1 = $ identity in $G$. Let $\phi: F_2 = \langle x,y | -\rangle \longrightarrow G$ be an injection. Then $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ are infinite order elements in $G$. Let $\phi(x) = g_i a^s$ and $\phi(y) = g_j a^t$. And now no matter what I do I cannot show that this cannot be possible. Maybe it is too simple but I have already spent a lot of time.

Do give a definition of a virtually cyclic group!

@HackR: If $P$ is a property that groups may have, then a group is "virtually $P$" if it contains a subgroup that has property $P$ and is of finite index in the group.

Thanks! I asked it because not everyone looking at the question might know the definition. A good practise is to always make your questions self complete as much as possible.

Here's another proof: a subgroup of a virtually cyclic group is virtually cyclic. From an old answer of mine, a torsion-free virtually cyclic group is cyclic. Now apply all this to $F_2\le G$ to reach a contradiction.

Let $\phi\colon F_2\to G$ be a morphism. We will prove it is not one-to-one.
Since $H$ is of finite index in $G$, it contains a normal subgroup $N$ of finite index in $G$. In particular, there exist positive integers $r$ and $s$ such that $\phi(x)^r=\phi(x^r)$ and $\phi(y)^s=\phi(y^s)$ lie in $N$. Since $N\subseteq H$, then $\phi(x^r)$ and $\phi(y^s)$ commute. Therefore, $\phi([x^r,y^s])=[\phi(x^r),\phi(y^s)]$ is trivial, proving that $\phi$ is not one-to-one, since in $F_2$ no nontrivial power of $x$ commutes with a nontrivial power of $y$.
Note that we don't need $H$ to be cyclic, just abelian.

Beat me to it! +1

It actually proves that the kernel must be "big" in some sense.

That's a very simple answer. Thanks a lot! There is just one tiny typo where $x$ should be replaced with $y$.

Here is another proof. A cyclic group is abelian, hence amenable, and a virtually cyclic group is virtually amenable, hence amenable itself. But $F_2$ is not amenable, so it cannot be a subgroup of a virtually cyclic group. This uses the fact that closed subgroups of amenable groups are amenable. So we have also shown that a virtually abelian group cannot contain $F_2$.
Reference: These notes by Alain Valette.

"It is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail." (nothing against this proof, this was just my first impression when I compared it with the other proofs! :))

+1. I like this, especially because "amenable" almost means (though certainly does not actually mean) "does not contain a copy of $F_2$."

Here is yet another proof.
Suppose $F \subset G$ is a subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $F_2$.
Since the infinite cyclic subgroup $H$ has finite index in $G$, it follows that $F \cap H$ has finite index in $F$ and $F \cap H$ is infinite cyclic.
However, there is a nice formula which says that if $n \ge 2$ then an index $m$ subgroup of $F_n$ is isomorphic to the free group $F_{1 - m + nm}$ (you can prove this formula with a bit of topology, the same bit used to prove that a subgroup of a free group is free).
So an index $m$ subgroup of $F_2$ is isomorphic to $F_{1 - m + 2m} = F_{1 + m}$. But $m \ge 1$, so $1+m \ge 2$, and $F_{1+m}$ is not infinite cyclic.

This actually works in more generality, i mean:
if $G$ contains a copy of $F_2$, and $H$ is a finite index subgroup of $G$, then $H$ must also contain a copy of $F_2$ (this is an exercise in Clara Loh’s textbook).
For a proof, this is my way to do it:
Let $F := \langle x, y \rangle \subset G$ be freely generated by $x$ and $y$. Since $H$ has finite index in $G$, there must be some $g \in G$ such that $x^n, x^m \in gH$ where $n > m > 0$.
So, there are $a, b \in H$ such that $x^n = ga$ and $x^m = gb$. Now, $x^mb^{-1} = g$ and therefore $x^{n - m} = b^{-1}a \in H$. Similarly, we find a power of $y$ living in $H$, and take the subgroup generated by them, which can easily be shown to be free of rank 2.
Now, back to the initial question, we just notice that a cyclic group can’t contain $F_2$.
